# How to switch order of network adapters in Vagrant under VirtualBox?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

Under Vagrant I have config something like this:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
     vb.memory = "512"
  end
  config.vm.host_name = 'core.example.com'
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: 2222, id: 'ssh'
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: '172.28.128.3'
  config.vm.synced_folder "./vagrant_core", "/vagrant", create: true
end
```

And after this I receiving something like that:

```
Adapter eth0 -> NAT
Adapter eth1 -> 'Private_network'
```

ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:cf:da:f3  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:8f:cb:52  
          inet addr:172.28.128.13  Bcast:172.28.128.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

Is there any way to switch them ? I need `private_network` under `eth0`.

Regarding to this topic [:adapter => 1](https://superuser.com/questions/752954/need-to-do-bridged-adapter-only-in-vagrant-no-nat) I can set my `private_network` as `adapter 1` but then I don't have NAT which I need, so what is, maybe, NAT network identifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can. It's fundamental assumption that Vagrant makes. Some parts of the code in Vagrant [make specific assumptions](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/ae8ace03fa3d5735599d4a092e0429063a98f191/templates/guests/debian/network_dhcp.erb) that eth0 = NAT.

However you might want to try renaming the interfaces after the machine is created.

Comment: I found this part of code also, but maybe You can provide some code to setup `eth1` as primary network interface?