# How can I define network settings with vagrant

Tags: vagrant

I am running Ubuntu inside vagrant, here is the Vagrantfile:

```
# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.99.4", :netmask => "255.255.255.0", auto_config: false
end
```

So I expect to have 192.168.99.4 as IP but I always have:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:88:ba:8f  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe88:ba8f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:9c:a9:9f 
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe9c:a99f/64 Scope:Link 
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

Any clue what I do wrong ?

Got some progress on the question, and it is almost like this one :
[How to switch order of network adapters in Vagrant under VirtualBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722563/how-to-switch-order-of-network-adapters-in-vagrant-under-virtualbox)

It is about not using "10.0.2.15" and from what I understand it is to be changed in the "NAT" setup of virutalbox, can not be managed by Vagrant

Comment: At what interface are you looking to?

Answer (score 13):

From the [vagrant book](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/vagrant-up-and/9781449336103/ch04.html)

> **NAT Requirement As the First Network Interface With VirtualBox**,
>
> Vagrant requires the first network device attached to the virtual
> machine to be a NAT device. The NAT device is used for port
> forwarding, which is how Vagrant gets SSH access to the virtual
> machine.
>
> Therefore, any host-only or bridged networks will be added as
> additional network devices and exposed to the virtual machine as
> “eth1,” “eth2,” and so on. “eth0” or “en0” is generally always the NAT
> device.
>
> It isn’t currently possible to override this requirement, but
> it is important to understand that it is in place.

so what you're reporting is this NAT.

Also eth1 is not defined as you set `auto_config: false` in your Vagrantfile so you're basically telling vagrant you'll do all the setup yourself. so you should turn this paramter to true (or remove) or set the `etc/network/interfaces` yourself

You can look at [vagrant public network](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/public_network.html) and look if you can use the snippet example to remove the eth0 gateway from your config

```
  config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.0.17"

  # default router
  config.vm.provision "shell",
    run: "always",
    inline: "route add default gw 192.168.0.1"

  # default router ipv6
  config.vm.provision "shell",
    run: "always",
    inline: "route -A inet6 add default gw fc00::1 eth1"

  # delete default gw on eth0
  config.vm.provision "shell",
    run: "always",
    inline: "eval `route -n | awk '{ if ($8 ==\"eth0\" && $2 != \"0.0.0.0\") print \"route del default gw \" $2; }'`"
```

Comment: Shows :HostName 127.0.0.1

Comment: ok I miss the part about `auto_config`, you're telling vagrant not to create the interface and you will create yourself - I remove also the ssh-config as it looks for vb its still 127.0.0.1 (I am using vmware where it shows the IP when private network)

Comment: Thanks, I deleted the auto_disable and got eth0 as 10.0.2.15 and eth1 as 192.168.99.4. But my initial motivation was to get rid of 10.0.2.15 which is conflicting with the local network outside. Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: @Gurvan - from what is described above it doesn't sound like it's feasible to do this when using Vagrant.

Comment: @slm and that's exactly what I want to do! The address range at the other end of a VPN tunnel is also 10.0.x.x and not getting to it is a bit of a crimp in my plans.

Comment: yes.. this is an issue as some tools... i.e. nomad. picks up the first available ip. which is 10.x.x.x in this case .. not the defined 192.x.x.x range

Answer (score 6):

To change the default NAT you should set it in Vagrantfile.

For instance:

```
 config.vm.define "bs" do |bvtserver|
  bvtserver.vm.hostname = "bvt-server"
  bvtserver.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.3",
      virtualbox__intnet: "gcptest-network"
  bvtserver.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vbox|
    vbox.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natnet1", "10.3/16"]
  end
end
```

For credits and more informations: [Li Chao blog](http://leetschau.github.io/bvt-environment-based-on-vagrant.html)

Answer (score 0):

I can bet you're looking at `eth0` (that's another interface). Look at `eth1` and you'll get what you're searching for. Moreover, from outside vagrant, try to ping it with

```
ping 192.168.99.4
```

Comment: Updated above, eth1 was not showing up so I did put it up, and does not take my ip