# Vagrant: Configure two NICs on guest (Host-Only adapter and NAT) on virtualbox

Tags: vagrant

I need to create a vm using vagrant with two network interface cards on virtualbox. I've configured them manually, but from now on, I need they are provided by vagrant.

So I need:

1. A `Host-Only Adapter` on 192.168.56.* with DHCP enabled.
2. A `NAT` adapter in order to be able guest get access beyond host.

Any ideas?

Currently, my host-only network adapters are:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vagrant will always configure a NAT (1st interface) so vagrant can communicate on ssh from host to VM (you can read https://stackoverflow.com/a/35211086/4296747 for more info)

After if you want to enable another network interface, vagrant will support the creation of an interface (check [vagrant network doc](https://www.vagrantup.com/intro/getting-started/networking.html)) and if you specify the interface, something likes this should work

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    config.vm.network "private_network", :type => 'dhcp', :name => 'vboxnet0', :adapter => 2
end
```

Comment: I've realized my virtualbox network configuration are name so largely like `VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adaper`. Is there any way to modify it or set a new network configuration up specifying a name like `vboxnet0`?

Comment: I've tried this: `config.vm.network "private_network", :type => 'dhcp', :name => 'VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter', :adapter => 2`. I'm getting this message: `A host only network interface you're attempting to configure via DHCP already has a conflicting host only adapter with DHCP enabled. The DHCP on this adapter is incompatible with the DHCP settings. Two host only network interfaces are not allowed to overlap, and each host only network interface can have only one DHCP server. Please reconfigure your host only network or remove the virtual machine using the other host only network.`

Comment: do you have other VM running on this adapter ?

Comment: Yes, but the other VM configured with this hostonly adapter is halted. I've edited the post showing my current hostonly adapters...

Comment: had the same issue, unable to use 'vboxnet0'

Comment: In my case, I first enabled a new 'host-only' adapter in virtualbox, just select your box, click 'settings', click 'network' and enable a different adapter than your other boxes have.
Then check the ip of that adapter by running 'ipconfig' in powershel or command line in Windows.

Finally, in vagrant specify an ip within the adapter's network:
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "place_ip_here"

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I did the following:
1) Enabled a new 'host-only' adapter in virtualbox: just select your box, click 'settings', click 'network' and enable a different adapter than your other boxes have.

2) Check the ip of that adapter you created by running 'ipconfig' in powershell or command line in Windows.

3) Finally, in your vagrant configuration file, specify an ip within the adapter's network: config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "place_ip_here".

If your adapter's ipv4 is '172.28.128.1', for example, and subnet mask '255.255.255.0', then your first three numbers in the IP remain the same '172.28.128.another_number_here'

Answer (score 0):

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
  config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
end
```

Works for me, though I already had 'vboxnet0' configured by default, it created a new host-only network 'vboxnet1'.

I was not able to use vboxnet0 further it throws conflicting network error. Creating multiple vms with above config worked for me using vboxnet1 by default.